# i want to get data from php file with ajax once per 5 min

Tags: php, ajax, phpexcel, phpexcelreader

I'm get data from excel file with php.After this data get from php file with ajax.In fact, I want to get data from excel file once per 5 min and print page.How can i do?

**data.php**

```
include "Classes/PHPExcel/IOFactory.php";


try {

     $url="https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1ngOuUvGk07r69HEonmYdjl9En1F1COAB8fAhNXNT1Y8/pub";//Bu url 'i load'ın içine girdiğimde File not exist hatası veriyor.Ben localde denemek için aşağıdak inputfile .
     $inputFile = 'a.xlsx';
     $objPhpExcel = PHPExcel_IOFactory::load($inputFile);
     $rows = $objPhpExcel->getActiveSheet()->toArray(null, true, true, true);

     $i=0;
     $data_en=array();
     $data_tr=array();
     $word=array();
        foreach ($rows as $row)
        {
            $i++;
            $data_en[$i] = $row['C'];
            $data_tr[$i]= $row['D'];
            echo $data_en[$i];echo "<br>";
        }


    }
catch(PHPExcel_Exception $e)
{
echo $e->getMessage();
}
```

**index.html**

```html
   
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function(){
        $.get("data.php", function(data){
            $('#container').html(data);
        });
    });
</script>
<body>
<p id="container"></p>

</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use setInterval() javascript function and set it to 5 minutes.

Answer (score 0):

> The JavaScript [setInterval()](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_setinterval.asp) function can be used to automate a task
>   using a regular time based trigger.
>   also you can clear scheduled work by [clearInterval()](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_clearinterval.asp)

it is a native JavaScript function.

```
var duplicateWork = setInterval(function() {
      // Do something every 1 seconds
}, 1000);

// To cancel scheduled work use similar code 

clearInterval(duplicateWork);
```

look at the example :

```js
var l = $('#list');

var duplicateWork = null;
var seconds = 1000 * 2;//2 second

$('#start').click(function(){
  $('#title').html('Start : add item once per 2 second');
  duplicateWork = setInterval(function() {
          // Do something every 2 seconds
      l.append('<li>duplicate work</li>');
    }, seconds);
});

$('#stop').click(function(){
  $('#title').html('Stop');
  clearInterval(duplicateWork);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="start">Start</button>
<button id="stop">Stop</button>
<h3 id="title"></h3>
<hr />
<ul id="list">

</ul>
```

In your case , you can use similar code

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    var seconds = 1000 * (60 * 5);//5 minute
    var refreshId = setInterval( function() {
        $.get("data.php", function(data){
            $('#container').html(data);
        });
    }, seconds);
});
```